# How can I despeciesize the word "dehumanize"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, synonyms, political-correctness

The word "dehumanize" is used to refer to the act of treating human beings without regards to their worth and human rights. In a setting with multiple sentient species, what word could replace "dehumanize"?

Comment: Neologisms aren't really what we do here, but I will suggest desentientize or something along that line - to treat an individual as non-sentient.

Comment: @Davo, *desentientize* would be far too easy to confuse with *desensitize*, which means something quite different.

Comment: @jsw29 How about desapientize or desophontize?

Comment: @Davo Isn't "despeciesize" a neologism itself?

Comment: You could go for *animalize*.

Comment: Are the sentient species all sub-human (eg fish, birds, monkeys)?

Comment: @Galactic yes, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of the many words with relevant overtones (such as abuse, mistreat, degrade, downgrade etc), I can only suggest one serious candidate that is not species-specific and avoids too much notion of abuse while representing an attitude of mind rather than physical behaviour:

> Objectify = to treat as an object (the complete quotation says: “or cause to have objective reality”, which is not relevant in this context)
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectify)

Comment: The problem is that _objectify_ means seeing someone _as_ something (an object). Whereas _dehuanize_ means seeing someone as _not_ something (removing their humanity).

Comment: @NigelTouch subtleties of meaning ... it might be argued that  if one is dehumanised, all that then remains is an object. And hence, one has been dehumanised by being objectified.

Comment: Only the first part of the quoted dictionary definition is relevant here; the second part unnecessarily confuses the matter. What the quoted definition does not say at all is that *to objectify* is often used in the sense of to treat someone as a **mere** object; it is in that sense that the word arguably fits the OP's purposes.

Comment: @jsw perfectly correct. I only had the first part in mind and perhaps should have said so but I do not wish to be seen as cherry-picking from dictionary so gave the complete quotation. Answer edited accordingly